# ASP.NET C# If else is ignored?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I've been scratching my head for over two hours. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Basically what I did was have "Winner" show up under status when I click on select bidder button. The problem is when I pick the bottom select bidder button then activate buttons above it. The if else decision that displays the error message "Cannot select winner. Error cause: You have already selected a winner." is ignored and proceeds to write "Winner" on the status field.

The error message will show if I try to do it the other way though. Pick the button in the first row to set the status to winner then picking the second row button will tell me I can't pick a winner because I already have picked somebody else.

**My C# code:**

```
protected void rptrBindBidders_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Winner" && e.CommandArgument.ToString() != "")
    {
        Int64 onsaleID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["saleID"]);

        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseSQLConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Bidders where saleID=" + onsaleID + " ", con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                string BidderStatus = dt.Rows[0]["BidderStatus"].ToString().Trim();

                if (BidderStatus == "Winner")
                {
                    lblmessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblmessage.Text = "Cannot select winner. Error cause: You have already selected a winner.";
                }

                else
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Bidders set [BidderStatus]='Winner' where [bidID]='" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "'", con))
                    {


                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        lblmessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        lblmessage.Text = "Success! A bidder has been selected!";


                        con.Close();

                    }
                }

                this.BindBidders();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrBindBidders" onItemCommand="rptrBindBidders_ItemCommand" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
   <table class="table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Bidders</th>
               <th>Date bidded</th>
               <th>Price Offer</th>
               <th>Status</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
            <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("BidderName") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("DateBidded") %></td>
                    <td>₱<%# Eval("bidPrice") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("BidderStatus") %></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnSelectBuyer" runat="server" Text="Select Bidder" CommandName="Winner" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("bidID") %>'/></td>
                    <!--<asp:HiddenField ID="hfbidID" Value='' runat="server" />-->
                    <!--<asp:HiddenField ID="hfBidderName" Value='' runat="server" />-->
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
   </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `If` is never ignored. `Else` is never ignored. The compiler always, always, always faithfully follows the instructions you give it. Put in a breakpoint and step through your code in the debugger and find out what it's actually doing. Hover the mouse over variables or use the watch window to understand why it does what it does. Find out what `BidderStatus` is. You can't learn anything about the world around you by making assumptions; you can learn only by going out and observing things.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `SqlDataReader` to check whether you have a winner directly, without having to fill a `DataTable`?

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cs)
{
    // SELECT 1 because we don't care about the returned data
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT 1 FROM [Bidders] WHERE saleID={onsaleID} AND BidderStatus='Winner'", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                // The command returned rows (there is an existing winner for the given `onsaleID`)
            }
            else
            {
                // The command returned no rows.  There is no winner.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa that did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused bidId and saleId. I guess that can exist many Bidders with same saleId and different BidId.
Basically you are just searching for all bidders and than check status for first one. So your code will evaluate this "  if (BidderStatus == "Winner")" to true only if first item is selected. Change Your select to "select count(1)", add where clause to select only winners and then check if it returns more than 0. It should work.